# Could Not build module 'Social'

Tags: ios

I am developing an iPhone app with ZXingWidget project included. I am using Xcode 5.1.1. I have added Social Framework for Facebook and Twitter sharing. When I tried to run the project in iOS Simulator it gives error as "Parse Error:Could not build module 'Social'". But when I removed ZXingWidget project and tried building my project, it runs successfully and I can share on FB and Twitter.
Can anybody knows what going wrong when I tried run my project with ZXingWidget included as sub project?
Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like they are conflicting. Are you developing some QR/Barcode scanning functionality? If yes, can you tell me why you go with ZXingWidget rather than AVFoundationFramework for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change In target setting the "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework modules" setting to YES

Comment: @shakti if you got your anwer, please upvote this answer. so that other also will get help from here.